# (R) How to exclude each current row's value from slide_index()'s window?

Tags: r, sliding-window

Hi I'm using slide_index() to capture values in a time window for every row in a dataframe. However, for every row I'll also be comparing the value of the current row against the captured values for that row's window. Part of the logic I'm using requires the current row's value to be excluded from the captured values during each row's iteration.

I think there are 2 ways to get around this: 1. I can pass in the current row's value directly into a custom function logic I'm using in slide_index(.f), or 2. I can exclude the current row's value from the values captured for the row's sliding window. I couldn't find any resources for the first route, so I'm wondering if the second route is feasible either.

```
library(slider)
x <- c(rep(1:16))
i <- as.Date("2019-08-15") + c(0:15)
slide_index(x, i, ~.x, .before = 2, .after = 2)
```

For example, going off the reproducible code above the output from slide_index() at the second iteration when x = 2 would be: [1] 1 2 3 4. But I'd want the output to either return only [1] 1  3 4, or get a way to read in the current x value into the custom function I'd pass into slide_index(.f)

**Edit:
Second example with group_by**

```
library(slider)
library(tidyverse)
x <- c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 25, 25, 33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13)
y <- c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 25, 25, 33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13)
group <- c(rep(as.character('A'), 5), rep(as.character('B'), 4), rep(as.character('C'), 1), rep(as.character('D'), 6))

df <- data.frame(group, x, y, dates) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(group))

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(mutate(., result = slide_index(.x = ., .i = .$dates, ~median(.$y), .before = 2, .after = 2) 
            %>% unlist()
                             ) 
            )
```

I also tried this but it didn't work

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(mutate(., result = max(map2(slide_index(.x = seq_along(.), .i = .$dates, .f = ~.$y, .before = 2, .after = 2), seq_along(.), ~.[setdiff(.x, .y)] )
                             )
            )
     )
```

Comment: What about for the first element - is it  2, 3?

Comment: If you run the code, at the first iteration when x = 1, the output from slide_index is [1] 1 2 3. So my goal would be for that output to change to [1] 2 3.

Comment: It is easier with `map2(slide_index(x, i, ~.x, .before = 2, .after = 2), x, setdiff)` within the `slide_index` to remove that element, it requires more effort than the `map2` code

Comment: That could work, but if there are duplicates in the x vector then wouldn't those duplicates be omitted by setdiff? My goal isn't to necessarily prevent the same value from popping up in both the current x element and output, but to ensure that the current x element isn't double-counted and included in the output.

Comment: For example:
 ```library(slider)
x <- c(c(1, 2, 2),rep(4:16))
i <- as.Date("2019-08-15") + c(0:15)
slide_index(x, i, ~.x, .before = 2, .after = 2)
```
I'd want the output for the second iteration (when x = 2) to be [1] 1 2 4 instead of [1] 1 2 2 4

Comment: Does the solution posted helps you

Comment: In the example new, what is the 'dates'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are duplicates, do the indexing with the sequence of values and then with `map2` remove that index and get the corresponding value

```
library(purrr)
library(slider)
i1 <- seq_along(x)
map2(slide_index(i1, i, ~.x, .before = 2, .after = 2),
            i1,  ~ x[setdiff(.x, .y)])
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 2

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 4

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 2 2 5 6

[[5]]
[1] 2 4 6 7

[[6]]
[1] 4 5 7 8

[[7]]
[1] 5 6 8 9

[[8]]
[1]  6  7  9 10

[[9]]
[1]  7  8 10 11

[[10]]
[1]  8  9 11 12

[[11]]
[1]  9 10 12 13

[[12]]
[1] 10 11 13 14

[[13]]
[1] 11 12 14 15

[[14]]
[1] 12 13 15 16

[[15]]
[1] 13 14 16

[[16]]
[1] 14 15
```

#### Update

If there is a grouped data, then we do a group by operation to create a `list` column

```
dates <- i
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   mutate(new = map2(slide_index(row_number(), dates, ~ .x, 
         .before = 2, .after = 2), row_number(), ~ x[setdiff(.x, .y)])) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 16 x 5
#   group     x     y dates      new      
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <list>   
# 1 A        10    10 2019-08-15 <dbl [2]>
# 2 A        12    12 2019-08-16 <dbl [3]>
# 3 A        12    12 2019-08-17 <dbl [4]>
# 4 A        14    14 2019-08-18 <dbl [3]>
# 5 A        11    11 2019-08-19 <dbl [2]>
# 6 B        22    22 2019-08-20 <dbl [2]>
# 7 B        25    25 2019-08-21 <dbl [3]>
# 8 B        25    25 2019-08-22 <dbl [3]>
# 9 B        33    33 2019-08-23 <dbl [2]>
#10 C        31    31 2019-08-24 <dbl [0]>
#11 D        34    34 2019-08-25 <dbl [2]>
#12 D        36    36 2019-08-26 <dbl [3]>
#13 D        23    23 2019-08-27 <dbl [4]>
#14 D        24    24 2019-08-28 <dbl [4]>
#15 D        29    29 2019-08-29 <dbl [3]>
#16 D        13    13 2019-08-30 <dbl [2]>
```

#### data

```
x <- c(c(1, 2, 2),rep(4:16)) 
i <- as.Date("2019-08-15") + c(0:15)
df <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
"D"), class = "factor"), x = c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 25, 25, 
33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13), y = c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 
25, 25, 33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13), dates = structure(c(18123, 
18124, 18125, 18126, 18127, 18128, 18129, 18130, 18131, 18132, 
18133, 18134, 18135, 18136, 18137, 18138), class = "Date")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: Hi yes I'm doing more testing, but this seems to work for my use-case. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @akrun do you know whether your seq_along() solution will work if I am using slide_index for grouped data after I use group_by on a dataframe? Example code below:

Comment: ```
library(slider)
library(tidyverse)
x <- c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 25, 25, 33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13)
y <- c(10, 12, 12, 14, 11, 22, 25, 25, 33, 31, 34, 36, 23, 24, 29, 13)
group <- c(rep(as.character('A'), 5), rep(as.character('B'), 4), rep(as.character('C'), 1), rep(as.character('D'), 6))

df <- data.frame(group, x, y, dates) %>%
  mutate(group = as.factor(group))

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  do(mutate(., result = slide_index(.x = ., .i = .$dates, ~median(.$y), .before = 2, .after = 2) 
            %>% unlist()
                             ) 
            ) 
```

Comment: I edited my original post with the code for this new example in a more clear format. So with the new example, I am trying to run slide_index() for the rows but now the rows are grouped. I have working code but am trying to make it work with your seq_along() solution so the current row values are removed from each slide_index() output

Comment: @r_so_throwaway let me know if the updates helps you.  I was away

Comment: How can I generate that df <- structure(....)?. Do you type everything?

Comment: @AlvaroMorales it is just `dput` i.e. if you want the head of the data structure `dput(head(iris))` and copy/paste the output.  The main benefit is that it can be used as a reproducible example (so that the column type and others will be the same)